# etcd - Is it possible to setup pubsub using etcd?

Tags: redis, docker, etcd

I would like to setup etcd / redis to store configuration params, applicable to all the docker containers (right now, only within a single host).

Would very much also need pub/sub mechanism - so that issuing certain *commands* is easy (like 'do git pull' to all containers, 'disable/enable certain common functions' etc).

I really like etcd (OOB curl based set/get, 17MB docker image), but I don't need the various availability, service discovery features of etcd for now - may be for later. As I understand, there is no pub/sub api with etcd (watching a key is the closest).

Please advise whether a pub/sub mechanism can be implemented effectively using etcd. Else I can go ahead with redis for now.

Comment: So publish==add a node, subscribe==watch the subtree. What else do you need?